# How to defn a function from string in Clojure?

Tags: function, clojure, metaprogramming, eval, defn

I'd like to do this (in REPL or anywhere)

```
(defn (symbol "print-string") [k] (println k))
```

and then be able to do

```
(print-string "lol")
```

Or, if there is any other way to create defn from custom strings in macroses, could you push me into the right direction please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
(defmacro defn-with-str [string args & body]
 `(defn ~(symbol string) ~args ~@body))

(defn-with-str "print-string" [k] (println k))

(print-string "lol")
```

Comment: 1. what is the ~ in front of args ? 2. what is the ~@ in front of body ?

Comment: @Belun 1. ~ = unquote  2.~@ = expand sequence

Comment: why is it that if I do (defn defns [] (doall (map (fn [s] (defn-with-str s [k] (println k))) ["print-string"]))) I get a fn called 's' ?

Comment: @Hendekagon macros aren't regular functions

Answer (score 17):

dnolen's solution works at macro expansion time, Brian Carper's at read-time. Now, here's one for run-time:

```
(intern *ns* (symbol "a") (fn [k] (println k)))
```

Comment: Cool did not know about that. One caveat is that the var a will be missing the function metadata that you get from using defn.

Answer (score 14):

I like dnolen's answer better, but you can do this too:

```
(defn #=(symbol "print-string") [k] (println k))
```

`#=()` is evaluated at read-time.  I don't know how stable a feature of Clojure this is, I wouldn't rely on it not to change in the future.  Macros are how I'd do it.

Answer (score 7):

FYI - dnolen's answer will only work for literal strings, and not for strings in def'd or let'd variables.

(defmacro defn-with-str [string args & body]
 `(defn ~(symbol string) ~args ~@body))

(def hisym "hi")
(defn-with-str hisym [] (println "hi"))

You now have a function called "hisym"

(hi) -> java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: hi in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:6)
(hisym) -> prints "hi"

To avoid this, eval the function name string in the macro

`` (defmacro defn-with-str [string args & body]

`(defn ~(symbol (eval string)) ~args ~@body)) ``